# Find the limit of given function as x approaches infinity

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\ lim_{x \to \infty} x^{4}{e^{-x^{2}}} $. Any tip how to start on this problem? I have no idea how to start on this type of problem.

Comment: $e^{x^2} >> x^4$ for $x$ large enough. So?

Comment: The easiest way to find the limit without L'Hospital is to find the taylor series for $e^{x^2}$ at $a=0$. We have $$e^{x^2}=1+x^2+x^4/2+x^6/6+O(x^8)$$ This immediately shows $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^4}=\infty$$ Take it from here.

Comment: Take the reciprocal!!! ;)

Comment: Just wondering why you don't want to use Le'Hopital? It seems very applicable in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify with $$x^4e^{-x^2}=4\left(\frac{x^2}2e^{-x^2/2}\right)^2=4\left(te^{-t}\right)^2$$ where $t\ge0$. Then you can solve just for $te^{-t}$.

L'Hospital will work. You can also use $e^t\ge1+t+\dfrac{t^2}2$ from Taylor.

Comment: Probably the simplest. If wonder if you did not miss a square for the last term in the first line. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: thanks for the notice, I was too much in haste to show the nice simplification :) . Notice that the trick works for all natural exponents $x^ne^{-x^m}$, and from there generalizes to polynomials $P(x)e^{-Q(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^4}{e^{x^2}}=\frac{x^4}{1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}+\frac{x^6}{3!}+...}=2!\frac{x^4}{x^4+2!(1+x^2+\frac{x^6}{3!}+....)}$$
$$\frac{2x^4}{x^4(1+2!(\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+....)}=\frac{2}{1+2!(\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+....)}$$
so the limit is $0$

Comment: Sorry, but it seems to me that something is missing in your argumentation (wothout words...): what use do you make of the $x^4$ term you have set apart in the denominator ?

Comment: @JeanMarie now I have added more details